# Deriving from and compositing same Class. C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, composition

What happens if a class has a "has-a" relationship with another class, and also it derives this same class?

```
class A
{
   friend classB;
   // here lots of things might be , but i just try to understand how should I think.
};

class B : public A
{
   // here again might be couple lines  of codes.

   protected:
      A d;
};
```

What is really going on here? How should I think about that?

Comment: What's your problem? My wife is-a mother and has-a mother. Is it hard to imagine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing particularly special with this. You have a member variable of `class A` called `d`, and your `class B` also contains everything that `class A` contains, and anything extra added to it.

I can't really see much useful from this at a glance, but I'm sure there are circumstances when it may come in handy - having a pointer to an A object would make more sense, in that it would make it a linked list (or similar).

Comment: Why there is an  friend classB; line in class A, I've already reach everything in A thanks to classB:public A. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Ok, so I didn't take that into account as "important" (your question wasn't clear in that respect). It allows `B` to access the content of `d` without going through accessor functions in `A`. Same as if you didn't have inheritance.

Comment: it refers to "friend classB;" ?

Comment: @L-caesar *friend classes* can access `private` members while *derived classes* cannot, so no you haven't "reached" everything in A only with `class B : public A`.

Comment: Yes, so B is a friend of A, which means that B can access all of "any" A object without the class A itself knowing about it. So if you have `class B { void doSomething(A a) { int x = a.private_int; cout <<< x; }`, this would work.

Comment: I want to summurize what i unserstood:

thanks to friend classB; I can reach everything inside A (private,protected public etc)

thanks to class B : public A, in my class B I have everything on A execpts privates

thanks to protected
   A d; :        I have a variable like int struct or something else ?

Comment: No, `d` has nothing to do with inheritance, but the `friend` declaration will allow B to access all of `d` no matter of public, private or protected.

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
struct Human {};

struct Superhuman : Human
{
    Human mentor;
};
```

Or perhaps a slightly less direct example:

```
struct Human
{
    virtual ~Human() {}
};

struct Girl : Human
{
    unique_ptr<Human> ptrToGirlfriendOrBoyfriend;
};

struct Boy : Human
{
    unique_ptr<Human> ptrToGirlfriendOrBoyfriend;
};
```

<sup>(Replace `unique_ptr` with `shared_ptr` as necessary…)</sup>

So there are times when composing the same type used for inheritance *does* make sense, though I'd suggest that it's fairly rare.

Lose the `friend` declaration, though, unless you really, *really* need it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see why you would ever want to use 'friend' here. By stating in A that B is a friend class, you're saying that A trusts B to access its private members. However, B derives from A, so if you want to access members in A from B, but not allow anything else access, then those members just need to be 'protected', instead of 'private'.

Comment: Like I said in my comment, the `friend B` declaration in `A` allows `B` to access, for example, private and protected fields of the `d` object inside `B` without need for `A`'s accessor functions.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I answered before your comment and failed to notice the instance of A! I still can't think of a design where you'd actually want to do this though.

Comment: No, I don't believe I've ever had to use this model either, but I'm sure there's some use for it in some bizarre part of the universe.

Comment: @Merlin069 maybe in real life there is no place for such an code but ,theorical you should know how piece of code like that act.

Comment: @L-caesar, I don't dispute that, but would be interested if anyone could provide such a case.